# In stylus, how do I use a variable inside of calc as a transform property value?

Tags: interpolation, stylus

Example:

```
paddingVar = 12px

.class
  transform scale(0.8) translateX(calc(20% - paddingVar))
```

Neither the curly braces nor the typical calc interpolation solution (`left "calc(50% - %s)" % arrow-size`) have worked for me.

When I try the above syntax [on the Stylus website](http://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=%24inner-padding%20%3D%2020px%0A%0A.thing%0A%20%20transform%20scale(0.8)%20translateX(%22calc(20%25%20-%20%25s)%22%20%25%20%24inner-padding)) it seems to work, but actually using it does not.

Answer (score 0):

The quoted syntax should work. The problem looks to be elsewhere in the build process.